# no sharing with samba after configuration

Tags: networking, samba

I have installed samba and have set up samba with the below commands

```
# mkdir -p /srv/samba/share
# chown nobody.nogroup /srv/samba/share/
# restart smbd
restart: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
# restart smb
restart: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
# /etc/init.d/smbd start
[ ok ] Starting smbd (via systemctl): smbd.service.
# /etc/init.d/smbd restart 
[ ok ] Restarting smbd (via systemctl): smbd.service.
# service smbd status
● smbd.service - LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/smbd)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2016-01-31 22:13:34 IST; 22s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 5883 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/smbd stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5893 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/smbd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/smbd.service
           ├─5909 /usr/sbin/smbd -D
           └─5927 /usr/sbin/smbd -D

Jan 31 22:13:33 acer-ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS d....
Jan 31 22:13:34 acer-ubuntu smbd[5893]: * Starting SMB/CIFS daemon smbd
Jan 31 22:13:34 acer-ubuntu smbd[5908]: [2016/01/31 22:13:34.717634,  0] ../...)
Jan 31 22:13:34 acer-ubuntu smbd[5908]:   Ignoring unknown parameter "passwo..."
Jan 31 22:13:34 acer-ubuntu smbd[5908]: [2016/01/31 22:13:34.723980,  0] ../...)
Jan 31 22:13:34 acer-ubuntu smbd[5908]:   Ignoring unknown parameter "update..."
Jan 31 22:13:34 acer-ubuntu smbd[5893]: ...done.
Jan 31 22:13:34 acer-ubuntu systemd[1]: Started LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS da....
Jan 31 22:13:34 acer-ubuntu smbd[5909]: [2016/01/31 22:13:34.884520,  0] ../...)
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Also,I have to much in my smb.conf file. I don't know where it came from. What I have set is the last `[share]` at the end of the file

```
[global]
netbios name = Samba24
server string = Samba file and print server
workgroup = Ubuntu
security = user
hosts allow = 127. 192.168.0.
interfaces = 127.0.0.1/8 192.168.0.0/24
bind interfaces only = yes
remote announce = 192.168.0.255
remote browse sync = 192.168.0.255
printcap name = cups
load printers = yes
cups options = raw
printing = cups
guest account = smbguest
log file = /var/log/samba/samba.log
max log size = 1000
null passwords = no
username level = 6
password level = 6
encrypt passwords = yes
unix password sync = yes
socket options = TCP_NODELAY SO_RCVBUF=8192 SO_SNDBUF=8192
local master = no
domain master = no
preferred master = no
domain logons = no
os level = 33
logon drive = m:
logon home = \\%L\homes\%u
logon path = \\%L\profiles\%u
logon script = %G.bat
time server = no
name resolve order = wins lmhosts bcast
wins support = no
wins proxy = no
dns proxy = no
preserve case = yes
short preserve case = yes
client use spnego = no
client signing = no
client schannel = no
server signing = no
server schannel = no
nt pipe support = yes
nt status support = yes
allow trusted domains = no
obey pam restrictions = yes
enable spoolss = yes
client plaintext auth = no
disable netbios = no
follow symlinks = no
update encrypted = yes
pam password change = no
passwd chat timeout = 120
hostname lookups = no
username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
passdb backend = tdbsam
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd '%u'
passwd chat = *New*password* %n\n *ReType*new*password* %n\n *passwd*changed*\n
add user script = /usr/sbin/useradd -d /dev/null -c 'Samba User Account' -s /dev/null '%u'
add user to group script=/usr/sbin/useradd -d /dev/null -c 'Samba User Account' -s /dev/null -g '%g' '%u'
add group script = /usr/sbin/groupadd '%g'
delete user script = /usr/sbin/userdel '%u'
delete user from group script = /usr/sbin/userdel '%u' '%g'
delete group script = /usr/sbin/groupdel '%g'
add machine script = /usr/sbin/useradd -d /dev/null -g sambamachines -c 'Samba Machine Account' -s /dev/null -M '%u'
machine password timeout = 120
idmap uid = 16777216-33554431
idmap gid = 16777216-33554431
template shell = /dev/null
winbind use default domain = yes
winbind separator = @
winbind cache time = 360
winbind trusted domains only = yes
winbind nested groups = no
winbind nss info = no
winbind refresh tickets = no
winbind offline logon = no

[homes]
comment = Home Directories
path = /home
valid users = %U
read only = no
available = yes
browseable = yes
writable = yes
guest ok = no
public = no
printable = no
locking = no
strict locking = no

[netlogon]
comment = Network Logon Service
path = /var/lib/samba/netlogon
read only = no
available = yes
browseable = yes
writable = no
guest ok = no
public = no
printable = no
locking = no
strict locking = no

[profiles]
comment = User Profiles
path = /var/lib/samba/profiles
read only = no
available = yes
browseable = yes
writable = yes
guest ok = no
public = no
printable = no
create mode = 0600
directory mask = 0700
locking = no
strict locking = no

[printers]
comment = All Printers
path = /var/spool/samba
browseable = yes
writable = no
guest ok = no
public = no
printable = yes
locking = no
strict locking = no

[pdf-documents]
path = /var/lib/samba/pdf-documents
comment = Converted PDF Documents
admin users = %U
available = yes
browseable = yes
writeable = yes
guest ok = yes
locking = no
strict locking = no

[pdf-printer]
path = /tmp
comment = PDF Printer Service
printable = yes
guest ok = yes
use client driver = yes
printing = bsd
print command = /usr/bin/gadmin-samba-pdf %s %u
lpq command =
lprm command =


[share]
    comment = This Ubuntu File share Server
    path = /srv/samba/share
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
    create mask = 0755
```

Comment: Samba, one of the famous nightmare-givers in linux land :) Doesn't fail to disappoint. I have the same problem, been too lazy to resolve it, but just to state the obvious, did you try disabling your firewalls? (If that fixes it, you need to port forward the proper ports). Also if you're trying to share with a windows machine, you may want to use nmbd as well.

Comment: whatever you are saying doesn't make any sense to me @Cestarian I have used Ubuntu file sharing before and it wasn't that complicated. Now I am struck but you need to elaborate your solution if you want to offer help. Also, where did firewall came? I am not on Windows :(

Comment: Just because it didn't require port forwarding once before, doesn't mean it doesn't require it now. And it's hardly complicated to turn off your firewall while troubleshooting network problems.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have fixed it. I deleted my messed up smb.conf file and started fresh.

To follow the step by step guide go to Ubuntu Forums. Stormbringer has an amazing easy to follow [guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=202605) for noobs.

You can also find the default smb.conf file there.

Comment: So, you just had a faulty config file, well thanks for the guide I guess, it might be of use to me as well.